# Can't generate compiled lisp executables

Tags: ros, catkin-make, roslisp, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following [tutorial on roslisp](http://wiki.ros.org/roslisp/Tutorials/OrganizingFiles#Generating_compiled_executables) with simple [talker and subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/roslisp/Tutorials/BasicUsage#Example_for_service_and_client).
My system is ROS indigo under ubuntu 14.04

During catkin_make I get the following errors, taking all the junk out:

> CMake Error at beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:135 (add_lisp_executable):

> Unknown CMake command "add_lisp_executable".

I have also tried to use rosbuild_add_lisp_executable instead, which gives

> [ 16%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp

> [ 16%] /bin/sh: 1: beginner_tutorials: not found/bin/sh: 1:

> beginner_tutorials: not found

> $ tail build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads

> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Thus, the tutorials seem to be obsolete.

Please advice how can I generate compiled lisp executable which I could run with the following command:

> rosrun lisp_tutorials talker

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206899/can%27t-generate-compiled-lisp-executables/) by [mukhachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/21666/mukhachev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-04-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a pull request hanging on roslisp that implements the `add_lisp_executable` functionality:
https://github.com/ros/roslisp/pull/19
I'll try to push for merging it into the official repo next week. Then it will be included in the next upcoming Hydro and Indigo release.

So, you can either wait for the next release or put the roslisp code into your workspace and merge that pull request.
Alternatively, you can just comment out the `add_lisp_executable` in the `CMakeLists.txt` of your tutorial ROS package and start the node from inside Lisp instead of `rosrun`. If you do need to generate an executable, there is also another alternative: you can create an executable script per hand (similar to the way it is done in Python) as it is described here:
http://wiki.ros.org/roslisp/Tutorials/OrganizingFiles#Using_roslisp_in_scripts

---

Originally posted by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) with karma: 311 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mukhachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/21666/mukhachev/) on 2015-04-09**:
Thanks, gaya. I do can launch my lisp scripts from REPL indeed. I was curious about making an executable since I was following the tutorial.